# getting MySQL error 1064 but very (absurdly) simple query in MySQLWorkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm getting a MySQL 1064 error for the simplest query when run with `\G` at the end. This works:

```
select * from locations;
```

and this doesn't:

```
select * from locations\G
```

hmmm... is there any way to see what the proper vertical representation is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`\G` is a delimiter exclusive to the mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html)

I personally do not use MySQL Workbench, but many others have done the following

- `Mar 12, 2010` : [How to get a table creation script in MySQL Workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2433133/491757)
- `Mar 28, 2012` : [\G like vertical output in MySQL Workbench for show engine innodb status](https://superuser.com/q/405984/76764)

But here is the Blog for MySQL Workbench Team ( [MySQL Workbench: Vertical Query Output](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2013/10/mysql-workbench-vertical-query-output/) )

**Give Them a Try !!!**

Comment: thx for insights - I have been a mysql client users and thought I'd give MySQL workbench a try (and possibly Sequel Pro). MySQL workbench seems ok - to be honest, I wish mysql client would be upgraded and get like a Vim revival. Two features I'd like (1) production mode - might require like a double return to run or if a destructive event like a confirmation that this is what you want to do (2) config where I could specify coloring based upon which db I'm in.

Answer (score 1):

After entering your SQL statement into the SQL editor (but without appending the \G), from the main navigation menu choose [**Query**] --> [**Execute Current Statement (*Vertical Text Output*)**]. This will output the results you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try with extra slash at the end of your query

```
select * from locations\\G;
```